# Error al enviar datos dentro de un modal

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap, modal

Hola tengo un formulario dentro de un modal e intento enviar un dato por el metodo post al controlador y me sale un error en el Bootstrap y el javaScript, no entiendo el error.

[image: error que muestra el navegador]

dejo mi codigo por si es util para ver el error

```
<div class="modal fade" id="nuevaCategoria" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Nueva Categoria</h2>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post" id="crearCategoria">
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                            <label for="categoria" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Categoria</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoria" name="categoria" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="guardar" name="save" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" >Crear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- 

Tengo todas las librerías necesarias en le footer

[image: librerias en el footer]

Comment: ¿El botón **submit** no va dentro del formulario?

Comment: Si estás importando _bootstrap.bundle_, ya estás importando _popper_, por cierto. Tus dos últimas importaciones son innecesarias. Además, el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Hola si el boton submit ya lo puse en el formulario @masterguru y gracias por el comentario padaleina lo voy a tener en cuenta.